How to Filter Data in PostgreSQL API Based on Multiple Languages?
I’m building an API where I need to filter data based on language. When filtering using a request like { "language": ["Hindi", "English"] }, I want to retrieve rows that match both languages, but only in the format "language": ["Hindi", "English"].
However, my data contains variations. For example:
In one row: "Language": ["English", "Hindi", "Punjabi"]
In another row: "Language": ["English", "Hindi"]
I want to send both rows in the desired format: "language": ["English", "Hindi"]. Importantly, I’d like to achieve this through a query rather than modifying the controller file.
Data: {
    "id": 169,
    "status": 1,
    "from_time": "10:30:00",
    "to_time": "19:30:00",
    "created_at": "2023-11-03 18:05:16",
    "updated_at": "2024-03-31 18:11:43",
    "language": ["English", "Hindi", "Punjabi"]
},
{
    "id": 817,
    "status": 1,
    "from_time": "10:00:00",
    "to_time": "17:30:00",
    "created_at": "2024-03-29 17:31:26",
    "updated_at": null,
    "language": ["English", "Hindi"]
}

Query Attempt:
SELECT *
FROM tbl_lang
WHERE language ->> 0 = 'Hindi' AND language ->> 1 = 'English'

I want to send both rows but only like "language": ["English", "Hindi"]. I don't want to sent one data like this "language": ["English", "Hindi","Punjabi"] or another data like this "language": ["English", "Hindi"].
Is this possible? If so, could someone provide the PostgreSQL query to achieve this?

If your column uses jsonb type, you can use the ?& operator (PostgreSQL 9.4+):

jsonb ?& text[] → boolean
Do all of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?

That way you can pass a single array/dict of the languages you want to match.
Demo at db<>fiddle:
select jsonb_pretty(data) from tbl_lang
where (data->'language') ?& array['English', 'Hindi'];

If you're working with a regular json, not jsonb, you  can add a cast:
select jsonb_pretty(data) from tbl_lang
where (data->'language')::jsonb ?& array['English', 'Hindi'];




jsonb_pretty




{    "id": 169,    "status": 1,    "to_time": "19:30:00",    "language": [        "English",        "Hindi",        "Punjabi"    ],    "from_time": "10:30:00",    "created_at": "2023-11-03 18:05:16",    "updated_at": "2024-03-31 18:11:43"}


{    "id": 817,    "status": 1,    "to_time": "17:30:00",    "language": [        "English",        "Hindi"    ],    "from_time": "10:00:00",    "created_at": "2024-03-29 17:31:26",    "updated_at": null}



The demo also shows how to speed up the query using a GIN expression index:
create index on tbl_lang using gin((data->'language') jsonb_ops);

It's available only for jsonb but it's reason enough to alter table tbl_lang alter column "data" type jsonb using "data"::jsonb;. A jsonb-type column is also lighter and faster to scan sequentially.
On 110k random samples, you can go down from an exec time of 437ms on sequentially scanned json column to 42ms for a sequential scan on a jsonb without the index, to 22ms using an index scan on jsonb.
explain analyze verbose 
select jsonb_pretty(data) from tbl_lang
where (data->'language') ?& array['English', 'Hindi'];




QUERY PLAN




Bitmap Heap Scan on public.tbl_lang  (cost=92.02..2659.95 rows=7996 width=32) (actual time=3.079..22.431 rows=6617 loops=1)


  Output: jsonb_pretty(data)


  Recheck Cond: ((tbl_lang.data -> 'language'::text) ?& '{English,Hindi}'::text[])


  Heap Blocks: exact=2284


  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tbl_lang_expr_idx  (cost=0.00..90.03 rows=7996 width=0) (actual time=2.735..2.735 rows=6617 loops=1)


        Index Cond: ((tbl_lang.data -> 'language'::text) ?& '{English,Hindi}'::text[])


Planning Time: 0.306 ms


Execution Time: 22.810 ms



